# (Fusing Layers Illegal instruction) when running detect.py of yolov5 on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, yolo, raspberry-pi4, yolov5

I have cloned the yolov5 repository in my raspberry pi OS
`git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5`

Updated torch and installed the requirements.txt file

However, when I run inference with detect.py
`python3 detect.py --source data/images --weights yolov5s.pt --conf 0.25`

It shows an error saying

```
detect: weights=['yolov5s.pt'], source=data/images, data=data/coco128.yaml, imgsz=[640, 640], conf_thres=0.25, iou_thres=0.45, max_det=1000, device=, view_img=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, nosave=False, classes=None, agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, visualize=False, update=False, project=runs/detect, name=exp, exist_ok=False, line_thickness=3, hide_labels=False, hide_conf=False, half=False, dnn=False, vid_stride=1
YOLOv5  v6.2-219-ga83d2a5 Python-3.9.2 torch-1.13.0 CPU

Fusing layers... 
Illegal instruction
```

I ensured I have installed the requirements and updated torch so I do not know what is going wrong, and I will appreciate any help